# Firebase custom event parameters not showing on firebase console events tab

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-analytics

I have the following custom event and I can't see the parameters of the event on the events tab on the firebase console. Is there anything wrong with my implementation ?

```
FirebaseAnalytics _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
await _analytics.logEvent(
name: 'complete_signup', parameters: {
"name": name,
"email": email,
"registration_date": registrationDate,
"registration_method": registrationMethod});
```

I see only the event on the console (events tab) but I see no parameters.

Comment: having the same problem, any solutions here?

Comment: You have to create them manually in the console

Answer (score -2):

If you can see the event on the events list, that means it’s successfully logged. If you are viewing the part that says “**Events in the last 30 minutes**”, the parameters will be empty if there’s no record of that particular event *in the last 30 minutes*.